# Is there a trunc function in C++?

Tags: c++, math

I searched around and couldn't find the `trunc` function for C++. I know I can do this:

```
int main()
{
    double a = 12.566789;
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << (int)(a * 100) / 100.0 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but I'm not sure it's the best way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: That is one way to do it. `trunc()` is another. You are looking for a truncation (trunc) function, not a big footlocker (trunk) function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`trunc` is there, in `<cmath>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
        std::cout << trunc(3.141516) << std::endl; 
}
```

I suppose you're looking for something else?

Comment: This isn't available in VS2010!!

Comment: So it isn't. Comparison of math.h per the POSIX, C90, C99 standards versus the Microsoft Studio implementation: http://www.johndcook.com/math_h.html .

Answer (score 22):

If your C library is so old that it lacks a `trunc` function (specified in C99), you can easily implement one based on `floor` and `ceil` (specified in C89)

```
double trunc(double d){ return (d>0) ? floor(d) : ceil(d) ; }
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a trunc function in C that you can use in C++

```
trunc(a*100)/100
```

Keep in mind that you still have to specify formatting requests, because floating point can't represent all real numbers exactly, and you could get output like `12.5600000001` or `12.55999999` if you don't tell the output code the precision you want.

TL;DR

Use the following for output:

```
cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << a<< endl;
```

And the following if you need a truncated result somewhere during a mathematical calculation:

```
trunc(a*100)/100
```

(Or better yet, use fixed-point math.)

Comment: When working with `double`, you want `trunc`, not `truncl` (which is for `long double`).

Comment: @Stephen: you're right. I didn't look too closely at the man page, and assumed that the first version was for `int`s, though that doesn't make any sense for `trunc`.

Comment: In VS2010, it says: "error C3861: 'trunc': identifier not found". Is it a standard function? I tested for trunc before asking this question. One more thing, `setprecision(2)` rounds the value, doesn't trunc.

Comment: @Alireza: `trunc` was added to the C standard with C99, hence it is not present on certain backwards C++ compilers that don't come with modern C libraries =/.  C++11 finally adds it to the C standard, so hopefully those vendors will finally modernize their math libraries in the next few years.

Comment: So meanwhile, I have to create my own version of it with the code I posted here. Right?

Comment: @Alireza: Your <math.h> should usable within C++ with most compilers. You may need to link with the C math library (although C++ does this au gratis on most systems). Regarding setprecision(2) rounding: You could have just used setprecision, period, and not bothered with the truncation. Your use of `(int)(a * 100)` is truncating.

Comment: @Alireza: see the other answers I've posted about how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Use the `trunc()` function from math.h. It's a C function, but it works as well in C++ as it does in C. If you want to keep a couple digits, you can always:

```
double a = 12.566789;
double b = trunc(a * 100) / 100.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an ancient C or C++ library that doesn't implement `trunc`, use [`boost::math::trunc`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/utils/rounding/trunc.html).

Comment: Well, it's not ancient. I use VS2010

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a very fast trunc-function:

```
double ftrunc( double d )
{
    static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(uint64_t), "sizeof(double) not equal to sizeof(uint64_t)");
    static_assert(numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559,  "double must be IEEE-754");
    // assume size_t is our CPU's native register-width
    static_assert(sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(uint64_t) || sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(uint32_t), "register-width must be 32 or 64 bit");
    if constexpr( sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(uint64_t) )
    // we have 64 bit registers
    {
        unsigned const MANTISSA_BITS           = 52,
                       EXP_BIAS                = 0x3FF,
                       INF_NAN_BASE            = 0x7FF;
        uint64_t const EXP_MASK                = (uint64_t)0x7FF                      << MANTISSA_BITS,
                       SIGN_MASK               = (uint64_t)0x800                      << MANTISSA_BITS ,
                       MIN_INTEGRAL_DIGITS_EXP = (uint64_t) EXP_BIAS                  << MANTISSA_BITS,
                       MIN_INTEGRAL_ONLY_EXP   = (uint64_t)(EXP_BIAS + MANTISSA_BITS) << MANTISSA_BITS,
                       INF_NAN_EXP             = (uint64_t)INF_NAN_BASE               << MANTISSA_BITS,
                       NEG_MANTISSA_MASK       = 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFu;
        union
        {
            double   du;
            uint64_t dx;
        };
        du = d;
        uint64_t exp = dx & EXP_MASK;
        if( exp >= MIN_INTEGRAL_DIGITS_EXP )
            // value has integral digits
            if( exp < MIN_INTEGRAL_ONLY_EXP )
            {
                // there are fraction-digits to mask out, mask them
                unsigned shift  = (unsigned)(exp >> MANTISSA_BITS) - EXP_BIAS;
                dx             &= ~(NEG_MANTISSA_MASK >> shift);
                return du;
            }
            else
                if( exp < INF_NAN_EXP )
                    // value is integral
                    return du;
                else
                    // infinite, NaN, SNaN
                    // raise exception on SNaN if necessary
                    return du + du;
        else
        {
            // below  +/-1.0
            // return +/-0.0
            dx &= SIGN_MASK;
            return du;
        }
    }
    else if constexpr( sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(uint32_t) )
    // we have 32 bit registers
    {
        unsigned const MANTISSA_BITS           = 52,
                       HI_MANTISSA_BITS        = 20,
                       EXP_BIAS                = 0x3FF,
                       INF_NAN_BASE            = 0x7FF;
        uint32_t const EXP_MASK                = (uint32_t)0x7FFu                        << HI_MANTISSA_BITS,
                       SIGN_MASK               = (uint32_t)0x800u                        << HI_MANTISSA_BITS,
                       MIN_INTEGRAL_DIGITS_EXP = (uint32_t) EXP_BIAS                     << HI_MANTISSA_BITS,
                       MAX_INTEGRAL32_EXP      = (uint32_t)(EXP_BIAS + HI_MANTISSA_BITS) << HI_MANTISSA_BITS,
                       MIN_INTEGRAL_ONLY_EXP   = (uint32_t)(EXP_BIAS + MANTISSA_BITS)    << HI_MANTISSA_BITS,
                       INF_NAN_EXP             = (uint32_t)INF_NAN_BASE                  << HI_MANTISSA_BITS,
                       NEG_HI_MANTISSA_MASK    = 0x000FFFFFu,
                       NEG_LO_MANTISSA_MASK    = 0xFFFFFFFFu;
        union
        {
            double du;
            struct
            {
                uint32_t dxLo;
                uint32_t dxHi;
            };
        };
        du = d;
        uint32_t exp = dxHi & EXP_MASK;
        if( exp >= MIN_INTEGRAL_DIGITS_EXP )
            // value has integral digits
            if( exp < MIN_INTEGRAL_ONLY_EXP )
                // there are fraction-digits to mask out
                if( exp <= MAX_INTEGRAL32_EXP )
                {
                    // the fraction digits are in the upper dword, mask them and zero the lower dword
                    unsigned shift  = (unsigned)(exp >> HI_MANTISSA_BITS) - EXP_BIAS;
                    dxHi           &= ~(NEG_HI_MANTISSA_MASK >> shift);
                    dxLo            = 0;
                    return du;
                }
                else
                {
                    // the fraction digits are in the lower dword, mask them
                    unsigned shift  = (unsigned)(exp >> HI_MANTISSA_BITS) - EXP_BIAS - HI_MANTISSA_BITS;
                    dxLo           &= ~(NEG_LO_MANTISSA_MASK >> shift);
                    return du;
                }
            else
                if( exp < INF_NAN_EXP )
                    // value is integral
                    return du;
                else
                    // infinite, NaN, SNaN
                    // raise exception on SNaN if necessary
                    return du + du;
        else
        {
            // below  +/-1.0
            // return +/-0.0
            dxHi &= SIGN_MASK;
            dxLo  = 0;
            return du;
        }
    }
}
```

It's faster than most implemementations. On my Ryzen 7 1800X the average execution-time of values >= 2^0 and <= 2^54 is 12 clock cycles.

Answer (score -1):

use `ceil` or `floor` from cmath

Comment: trunc() does exactly what the OP wants. ceil and floor don't.

Comment: If his C library is so old that it lacks a `trunc` function, then he can easily implement `double trunc(double d){ return (d>0) ? floor(d) : ceil(d) ; }`