# Should I explicitly trunc?

Tags: c++

Given this starting point:

```
double y = readDoubleValue();
```

Is there any significant difference in C++ between:

```
int x = y;
```

and

```
int x = trunc(y);
```

Which one should I prefer? If somebody else (including my future self :) ) reads my code, it looks to me that with the second it's more explicit the fact that I know exactly what I am doing, however it requires a library inclusion.

Reference:
[Is there a trunc function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709405/is-there-a-trunc-function-in-c)

Comment: If I looked at the `trunc` version, I would think "What?? Surely trunc does... " then I would waste a few minutes reading documentation for no reason. So if anything, it obfuscates the code for me.

Comment: This seems to be an uncommon opinion, at least with the people who write code I have to maintain, but *comments are ok!*. I would write `int x = y; // deliberately truncate` or something (better - explain *why*, but I don't know that from this snippet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just using `static_cast<int>(y)` will give all the benefits you are looking for:

1. truncation
2. the casting
3. explicit conversion for clarity.

the reasons why I won't use `trunc()`

1. it is not that common, and probably someone else reading your code will have to review the documentation (that is why I did, but again, I'm not an expert)
2. you are still using implicit conversion anyway, `trunc()` doesn't return an int.
3. for me it is not explicit enough, after reading your code and the documentation I asked myself this: "did he intent casting to int, or you just wanted a float without the fraction part"

I can think of a situation or two where I want to get rid of the fraction part but I still want to the variable to have the  type `float` for several reasons like, I want the operation `x + 0.1f` to save the fraction part.
so I still would have doubts about your intentions, maybe you didn't mean the implicit conversion.

**OR** you can just put a little comment next to it `int x = y; // yes, I know what I'm doing`.
This will also give the clarity you need.

Comment: +1 - good answer.  Another reason is the performance cost... on x86 sans SSE2/3 one programmer concluded 40 cycles for his system (link provided at end), and conversion will only be done again anyway when the Standard Conversion from truncated `double` to `int` stores the result.  Link: http://www.masmforum.com/board/index.php?PHPSESSID=786dd40408172108b65a5a36b09c88c0&topic=7758.0;prev_next=prev

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There's also a computation benefit that might be worth mentioning. Anyway, my personal choice at this point goes to adding a comment.

Comment: Somebody had mentioned the trunc call would be "optimized away"; for completeness this is a [non-exaustive counterproof](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#{%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A{%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue}%2C%22compilers%22%3A[{%22source%22%3A%22%23include%20\%22math.h\%22\n\nint%20test%28double%20input%29%20{\n%20%20return%20input%3B\n}\n\nint%20test2%28double%20input%29%20{\n%20%20return%20trunc%28input%29%3B\n}\n%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fg%2B%2B-4.8%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O2%20-fomit-frame-pointer%20-march%3Dnative%22}]})

Answer (score 1):

IMO you should not. The truncate is a function defined for floating point types. It does not change type into integral type.

`int x = y;` here you say you are assigning something to an int variable

`int x = trunc(y);` here you say you drop the fractional part part for whatever reason, then convert

Use-cases are pretty different in my opinion.

Why would I discourage use of `trunc` before conversion. Probably preference, to me its kind of obfuscation actually in such use-case.

Comment: Why is `trunc(3.1f)` unequal  `3` value wise assuming the result of truncating is int?

Comment: Well `trunc(3.1f)` is not `int` its `float`. I know it gets converted right afterwards. I dunno, it maybe something OCD like, knowing its not exact value, so what is the point of double converting/truncating anyways.

Comment: Value wise it should be the same. IEEE floating point can represent all 32 bit integers accurately. Type-wise you are right.

Comment: @RedX Ok, I trust you know more than me. I edited my answer. I am sure you cannot express the same numbers as in base 10 system (in finite length). Thanks for correcting me and expanding mu knowledge!

Comment: I disagree with your wording. `std::trunk` does not drop the _mantissa_. It drops the _fractional part_.

Comment: @lrineau I edited it for the clarity. I knew the word *mantissa* by its usage for the meaning of *fractional part*. But I see there can be some confusion, and I probably misused it too.

Comment: @RedX `IEEE floating point can represent all 32 bit integers accurately.` I don't think this is correct, a float might have down to 23bits of mantissa, when a typical integer has 31 bit (1 bit is for the sign). A float typically cannot precisely represent a value like `0x7ffffffe`, like in [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0d90b5a958808e0).

Comment: @luk32 `Well trunc(3.1f) is not int its float`. To be more precise, it's `double`, not `float`. `truncf` is `float`.

Comment: @Antonio http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc says something different. Question is tagged `c++`. It is supposed to give the same type that input had, except for `Integer` types and then it is `double` indeed, but `3.1f` is `float` I believe.

Comment: @luk32 Apparently is one of those things that [changed with C++11](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/trunc/): I WAS right, you ARE right :)