# c++ caring about only 2 digit decimal w/o setprecision

Tags: c++, floating-point, decimal, precision

double i = 2.5373737373737....

Is there anyway to get rid of decimals after 2 digits decimals so it can be 2.57? (without displaying it by using setprecision)

Comment: First off don't use an `int`

Comment: <cmath> has a round() function.  If you want to truncate see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6709405/is-there-a-trunc-function-in-c

Comment: Note that rounding 2.5373737 would _not_ round to 2.57 -- it would round to 2.54

Answer (score 0):

setprecision(int) function in iomanip can help to print with required precision.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main () {
double i =2.537373737;
std::cout << setprecision(3) << i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: The question asks to not use `setprecision()`.